# Audio output with A2DP and audio input with HFP can be used at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, a2dp, hfp

I want to develop the application to input the voice from the microphone of the Bluetooth headset and to output into the Bluetooth speaker.

I think that use of HFP to input and A2DP to output. 
The two profile can be used at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I'm interested in this as well. From what I can find, it sounds possible but I've yet to see many hardware vendors specifically market it as a feature.

Creative recently released their BT-W2 bluetooth dongle that supports what they're calling a "voice-back channel". Might be similar to what we're talking about but it's hard to find tech specs that confirm it.

Below is a link to some documentation I found on the Bluetooth SIG website that appears to support the fact that it's possible. Maybe it'll help you:

https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=296662

Comment: Voice-back channel is a way to (ab)use A2DP protocol against the spec to send voice data back. It's a feature of FastStream and APTX-LL A2DP codecs. HSP/HFP is not used in this mode.